# Implementation of Assignment operator

Tags: c, assignment-operator

Can i write assignment operator in a cascaded manner.Following are two statements how can i write them

```
 total_marks/=1000;
 total_marks*=100;
```

Can we do something like but where we place 100

```
total_marks*=total_marks/=1000;
```

Comment: There are no assignment operators in your code. I think you need to clarify the terminology.

Comment: total_marks=total_marks/1000; It assigns value to total_marks.isnt it?

Comment: @juanchopanza What would you call `/=` and `*=` ?

Comment: @user3386109 where I should place 100?

Comment: Your first code snippet is the correct way to do it.

Comment: What's wrong with the simple, readable, `total_marks = (total_marks / 1000) * 100`?

Comment: nothing,I just wanted it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you could write for example

```
( total_marks/=1000 ) *= 100;
```

However in C this code will not compile.

In C ( and C++ ) you could write the following way using the comma operator

```
total_marks/=1000, total_marks *= 100;
```

I mean if you need this in expressions.

Comment: @sony  In C the assignment operator returns rvalue.

Comment: Operators in C++ usually return a reference to the object doing the operation. In this case "total_marks". In C these operations return a value and not a reference, so you cannot assign values.

Answer (score 4):

No. The result of a `/=` or `*=` operator will not return an lvalue, and therefore cannot be used to the left of another assignment.  What's wrong with the simple, obvious, readable:

```
total_marks = (total_marks / 1000) * 100;
```

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, but disagree with the first line of the answer. The assignment operators evaluate from right-to-left. So for example `int a=10,b=2; a+=b*=3;` is perfectly valid and sets `a=16` and `b=6`.

Comment: You're right, but that won't help him do what he was trying to do.